ReactJS: Remove word from key
I have:
const filteredItemsF = categorizedDataFoods2[key]?.items.filter(item => item.packingLocation === location);

This returns an undefined, because I think categorizedDataFoods2 returns:
{
    "PACK - A": {
        "items": [
            {
                "Category": "BREAKFAST",
                "Name": "Bacon (300g)",
                "Quantity": "1",
                "Weight": "0.400",
                "packingLocation": "PACK - A",
                "bought": false,
                "packed": false,
                "id": "T2ajRjW7uahiFm2NLspG"
            }
        ]
    },
    "PACK - B": {
        "items": [
            {
                "Category": "BREAKFAST",
                "Name": "Blueberries",
                "Quantity": "1",
                "Weight": 0.125,
                "packingLocation": "PACK - B",
                "bought": false,
                "packed": false,
                "id": "76412f40-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3"
            }
        ]
    }
}

However I need the [key] to strip the words "PACK - " so the [key] only returns A or B. Same goes for packingLocation - this should only be A or B. Is that possible?

You can use
const strippedKey = key.replace('PACK - ', '');

To remove PACK -  from the original key without modifying your original object.
So now it will be:
const strippedKey = key.replace('PACK - ', '');
const filteredItemsF = categorizedDataFoods2[strippedKey]?.items.filter(item => item.packingLocation === location);

